# Querying all ParseUser from parse database, returning 0 objects

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im currently trying to populate my `ListView` with `ParseUsers` from my Parse.com database. I have tried the below code with another class and that worked fine. I dont understand why the `ParseUser` is returning 0 objects. Is it not allowed to query for `ParseUsers` because they have passwords?

```
void getUsers(final AdminSearchActivity adminSearchActivity){
    ParseQuery<User> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(User.class);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<User>() {
        public void done(List<User> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                System.out.println(objects.size());
                for(User u: objects){
                    System.out.println(u.getName());
                }
                adminSearchActivity.populateListView(objects);
            } else {
                Log.d("ParseError", e.toString());
                doToastMessageInView(adminSearchActivity, "ERROR: Failed to retrieve users.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Outputs `"I/System.out: 0"`

```
void getUsers(final AdminSearchActivity adminSearchActivity){
    ParseQuery<Branch> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Branch.class);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Branch>() {
        public void done(List<Branch> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                System.out.println(objects.size());
                for(Branch u: objects){
                    System.out.println(u.getName());
                }
                adminSearchActivity.populateListView(objects);
            } else {
                Log.d("ParseError", e.toString());
                doToastMessageInView(adminSearchActivity, "ERROR: Failed to retrieve users.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Outputs `"I/System.out: 2"`

[Here is an image of my table  overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtdsH.png)

Comment: use like this `ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryParseUser = ParseUser.getQuery();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Found a solution before seeing your post. Yours is simpler. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, you are allowed to query other users, but not allowed to modify them on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. We used `@ParseClassName("user")` in our "User" class. Should've user `@ParseClassName("_User")`. That is why the query wasn't looking in the right table.

EDIT: kishore jethava provided a simpler solution in a reply. Havent tested that but should be easier

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryParseUser = ParseUser.getQuery(); //  kishore jethava
```